# API raw data request gives me nothing

Tags: facebook-analytics

I've made my request week ago, and still have status:

```
"id": "304761766596473",
"start_ts": "2017-10-16T12:37:48+0000",
"end_ts": "2017-10-17T12:37:48+0000",
"status": "SCHEDULED",
```

What does it mean? Should I wait my data or have to do it again?

Comment: Any further context?

Comment: @MilanVelebit I want to get my app raw data from Facebook Analytics for two days. I made my request week ago. And still have  status: "Scheduled". I can't understand when my raw data comes? Or I did something wrong and need to remake my request?